# php 5.4 mail include template ob_start and file_get_contents

Tags: php, email

I have a script called ajaxdb.php that had sent an email to the user as confirmation for his entry. I updated the php version to 5.4 for other needs. But now this code doesn't return valid html for the Clients. For example in GMX I just get displayed plain text. When I use ob statement flush it displays the external template correctly but under my script and not in the mail. I tried a lot written in other stackoverflow comments, but till now nothing helped me out.

I took a look the Documentation and also tried around for ob_start() with `ob_start(null, 0, PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_STDFLAGS ^ PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_REMOVABLE);`

Maybe anyone have a clou for it or can advice other slim solutions for confirmation mails with php and external templates(that are correctly filled with variables).

```
  $contents = file_get_contents('mailing.php', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

//alternatively tried
    #ob_start();
      #include "mailing.php";
      #$contents = ob_get_contents();
    #ob_end_clean();

  $absender   = $who;
  $antwortan  = $sender;

  $header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

  $header .= "From: $absender <$sender>\r\n";
  $header .= "Reply-To: $antwortan\r\n";
  // $header .= "Cc: $cc\r\n";  // falls an CC gesendet werden soll
  $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP 5.3";
  $betreff = "Vielen Dank ". $name .", du stehst auf der Gästeliste";
  $betreff = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($betreff)."?=";

// send the email
mail ($mail, $betreff, $contents, $header);
```

Comment: What is in mailing.php?

Comment: mailing.php is an html template that is filled with <?php echo ?> comments

Comment: I guess that is because its content should be dynamic? (There are more elegant solutions for this). file_get_contents won't work this way. ob_get_contents should work. Use a library to send HTML mails.

Comment: Can you advice a slim one? I read about swift and phpmailer. Is it advisable to take a look at "PHP's IMAP functions" or better skip this out?

Comment: This looks good: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
No, you don't need IMAP for this.